# Flutter release apk not working correcty but debug app works fine

Tags: flutter, dart

I've built simple meme/photo editor app using flutter.It is working perfectly in debug mode but It's not working in release mode.There is a container in my app which is used to show user image loaded using image picker.When I select image in debug app it's showing but when tried it in release version It shows only a blank container and also it alignments are changed.I've tried `flutter clean` and have added the `Internet permission` to manifest file.But nothing correct that issue.

Also I've tried app bundle and split apks but Issue is remaining.Is there any method to generate and upload debug apk to playstore without getting any security issues?

This is the part with issues...It is working correctly in debug but not in release mode.

```
 Center(child: Stack(
           children: <Widget>[
             _image != null ?  Expanded(
                       child: Container(
                       child: Image.file(
                        _image,
                        height: 400,
                        width: 400,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                              ),
                            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem disappeared when I replaced the expanded with container..Thanks for support

Answer (score 11):

By what you've shared (which is not a lot) I can assume you've missed adding the `INTERNET` permission on the `main` manifest.

Usually 3 manifests are created. Open your `android/app/src` folder, you'll see 3 subfolders:

- debug
- profile
- main

It's easy to be mistaken and put the permission in the wrong Manifest, I've been there some times!

Comment: No I've checked it...I've paced it in correct mainfest file.I cannot find what causing the problem.

Comment: Can you share some more info? How do you get the image? What's the code having the issue? Does the console say anything?

Comment: this is what work for me, thanks you saved my day, for anyone  want to see how to do it 
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/networking

Answer (score 4):

**I had this exact problem. I solved it with these solutions:**

1. Add android/app/proguard-rules.pro

   ```
   #Flutter Wrapper
   -keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
   -keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
   -keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
   -keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
   -keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
   -keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
   -keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; } 
   -keep @interface com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
   -keep @interface com.google.gson.annotations.Expose
   -keepattributes *Annotation*
    #https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58479
    #https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/flutter-and-android-obfuscation-8768ac544421
   ```
2. add proguard to buildTypes in app level build.gradle

   ```
   buildTypes {
   release {
       profile {
           matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
       }
   minifyEnabled true
   useProguard true
   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   signingConfig signingConfigs.release
   }
   }
   lintOptions {
   disable 'InvalidPackage'
   checkReleaseBuilds false
   }
   ```
3. edit the kotlin main activity file:

   ```
   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
   import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
   import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

   class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
        override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
         GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

It's probably because your app requires internet connection, but you haven't specified this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file at: yourProject/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Confirm whether the internet permission is enabled.

**Before:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<application...
```

**Now:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application..
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

remove unnecessary Expanded() from UI code

Answer (score 0):

Hi Axen_Ranges sorry I am late to the party.
Today I experienced the same behavior.
The fix was to remove the Expanded() from my UI code. It seems there is a problem with some types of layouts.

Earlier I had a Column() with an Expanded(). This works! :)

```
 body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(height: 30.0),
      logoSection,
      logoTextSection,
      Expanded(
        child: Column(children: [
          userImageSection,
          infoTextSection,
        ])
      ),
      pleaseConfirmSection,
      buttonSection,
      ],
    ),
  )
```

I changed the Column() into a Scrollbar() with a ListView(), still containing the Expanded(), this does not work! :(

```
body: Scrollbar(
    isAlwaysShown: true,
    controller: _scrollController,
    child: ListView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      primary: false,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 30.0),
        logoSection,
        logoTextSection,
        Expanded(   // This Expanded() does not work with Scrollbar() or ListView() removing it fixes everything :)
          child: Column(
            children: [
              userImageSection,
              infoTextSection,
            ]
          )
        ),
        pleaseConfirmSection,
        buttonSection,
      ],
    ),
  )
```

The problem here is that the flutter framework does not tell you that there is a problem.
It works no problem in debug mode. But in release mode it only shows an empty container.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by removing expanded widget,

My debug mode was working perfect but when I release Apk bundle to publish the main screen was not showing images and detail so I just remove Expanded widget by container and it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very good solution for this .It also work for packages like autoscale_tabbarview that work perfectly fine on debug mode but causes problem in release mode. Just like the above comment add proguard for all plugins.

1. Create ProGuard Rules File:

In your Flutter project's 'android/app' directory, create a file named 'proguard-rules.pro' if it doesn't already exist.

```
#Flutter Wrapper

-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

2. Update build.gradle:

In your 'android/app/build.gradle' file, make sure that the proguardFiles directive includes the custom rules file you created. The proguardFiles line should look like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

3. Update MainActivity.java:

In your 'MainActivity.java' file, add the below code and for .kt file you can see above comments or can ask chatgpt to convert into .kt file

```
package com.example.pettera_project;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to change the package name.